# Load a FLV video on Flash without method GET

Tags: flash, actionscript, video, flv

I want load a video on flash, without a GET call to get the video...
now the code is something like this:

```
var Player:FLVPlayback = attachMovie("FLVPlayback", "Player", _root.getDepth()-1);
Player.autoPlay=false;
Player.bufferingBar=buff;
Player.contentPath="myVIDEO.flv";
```

the problem is when myVIDEO.flv are loaded, this URL appers on firebug...
Someone can help me?
Thanks
Rodrigo

Answer (score 0):

Is this Actionscript 2 or 3? If its 3, my advice would be to use the [Video class](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/media/Video.html).

I don't understand what you mean by not using a GET call. And what URL in Firebug?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like you are trying to prevent the user from downloading your video.  You have concerns that the loaded content shows up as a request in Firebug, and perhaps the user can use that link to download your vids directly.

If you load **ANYTHING**, it will show up as a request in Firebug (or Charles, or any other http header viewing tool).  I don't know of any way for you to load content without a GET request being generated.  You will need to look into alternate methods for protecting your content (domain locking, nested containers, etc).